# c# equivalent for c++/cli long

Tags: c#, types, c++-cli

I declared a method of in C# like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(MyException))]
MyClass MyMethod(... some params ..., Int32[] myParam);
```

And in C++/CLI a need to write the method matching the interface:

```
MyClass^ MyMethod(... some params ..., array<long>^ myParam) { ...
```

I need to trasfer array of longs for C++ world from .Net. I know that C++ long is not the .Net long. But I don't know how to make this.

Comment: I thought a long in C++ was a signed 4 byte integer? This is the same as a .Net Int32.

Comment: @chibacity: It is. This is also something that's implementation dependent.

Comment: @Philip, you just missed a perfect opportunity not to post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the C++ compiler for MSVC, `long` and `int` have the same size. I'm not sure if you're thinking of `long long` which represents a 64-bit signed integer in MSVC. If you mean just `long` though, then `Int32` within .Net should be fine.

To be really safe, you can use the provided macros for signed 32-bit integers:

```
#include <cstdint>

MyClass^ MyMethod(... params ..., array<int32_t>^ myParam) { ...
```

Or better yet, using the .NET defined types as Alexandre C recommends:

```
MyClass^ MyMethod(... params ..., array<System::Int32>^ myParam) { ...
```

**The most important thing to take note of is that `int`, `long`, `int32_t`, and `System::Int32` are all the same exact size in the current MSVC C++ compiler. It doesn't matter which you use, but `int32_t` and `System::Int32` are the safest choices.**

Microsoft can change their `long` at a later date to be a size larger 32-bits. If that were to happen, then you could recompile this same code with the new compiler with zero issues.

With regards to what size each data type is, the standard requires that `int` and `long` are at least 4 bytes large. On some compilers, you may find that `sizeof(long) != sizeof(int)`. For that reason, if you want to make sure that you're using integers that are exactly 4 bytes big you should use the provided headers that guarantee the required size.

For more details see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_integer. The article includes the relevant links to the standards.

Comment: In C++ I need long (not long long). In C# I can declare anything.

Comment: Then use either `int`, `long`, or `System::Int32`. All three are exactly equivalent. I think `System::Int32` best describes your intent though.

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with `System::Int32` (or simply `Int32` since most C++/CLI source files have `using namespace System`) ?

```
MyClass^ MyMethod(... some params ..., array<Int32>^ myParam)
```

As a rule, use .NET types when you talk to .NET.

Comment: Good point. I forgot that there's `System::Int32` within C++/CLI

Comment: I need to add a long variable to the collection of longs which is C++ structure.

Comment: @vasek7: a `long` is the same as a `System::Int32` in the C++ compiler for MSVC.

Comment: @Mike, @vasek7: using `System::Int32` is only to ensure that prototypes for C++ and .NET are the same, without having to guess anything. Converting a Int32 to a `long` in the C++ side is straightforward (and probably a no-op as you point out).

Answer (score 0):

`long` and `int` in C++ have same size (4 bytes) and are both mapped to .NET type System.Int32. However, `long`, when used as a parameter or in a field, has the optional modifier `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong` (in CIL, it is `int32 modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsLong)`)

This allows you to create method overloads differing only in `int`/`long` parameter.